# project architecture for managing code sharing between apps (react / backend)

Tags: reactjs, architecture

## The situation :

2 apps with back-ends, different front dependencies & versions (react, router, types, etc). One as an user service, the other as an admin settings app. Each with own login system.

## The goal :

Develop a third app of users management accessible from the service app (logged as team manager) & from the settings app (logged as admin with more features)

## The question :

Which organization to implement for the project ?

1. Distinct folder with own client part & front dependencies. In this case, how can the 2 login systems follow ?
2. New client parts in each two apps with code sharing for commom components. In this case, how to manage a new front structure, build, packages…

Thanx for leads

Comment: are the backends javascript as well?

Comment: nope, backends are scala btw